# Kubernetes - Can I start a pod with a container without any process?

Tags: kubernetes

We have a docker image. And am trying to deploy it using kubernetes. My doubt is can I deploy a pod with a single container but not run any process in the container while the container comes up? But run it after it starts. That is, after the container starts, go into the bash of the container, and run the process(lets say a java process)? Is that possible?

Right now, when I am trying to deploy a pod with no process running, I get this error :

> Back-off restarting failed docker container
>   Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "containerName" with CrashLoopBackOff:

But when I start the container with a java process, it works. Am not sure if its because of no process in container? Please guide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're trying to do sounds like an antipattern anyways you can do with with the sleep process e.g. like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: app
spec:
  containers:
  - name: app-container
    image: app-image:version
    command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "--" ]
    args: [ "while true; do sleep 30; done;" ]
```

You could then run your process **BUT**:

- You container will not be bound to the seconds process and would not end when your second process ends
- You have to do manual work
- You could save if you'd just run your application in the `command` of the container

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Could you elaborate on the 3rd point? Didn't understand it properly.

Comment: Would you please explain what you have done in the command and args?

Comment: @Nagireddy Hanisha ... this starts a bash script and passes the actual script as one argument string to it. The script itself runs sleep in a loop.

Comment: @Tarun - could you update your question and show the command which you run manually?

Comment: @pagid and nagireddy - I did not understand the 3rd point exactly and didn't try this, But similar to this a bit differently, I ran a java process in the container with infinite loop(instead of a sleep). That made sure I had a container running and then, went inside the container and started the desired java process. Am not sure if I should update that in the question.? Thanks a lot for your answer pagid, it gave me an idea for this solution!

Comment: @Tarun ... maybe just add it as a comment on the question - which processes did you start when, I'm pretty sure you can work around the endless sleep.

Comment: @pagid, noticed that one of the R language pods were exiting with exit code 137, root cause appeared to the sleep timeout that was tool small since Kubernetes killed the pod after the timeout. Took a while to find out what was happening with those pods. They shouldn't have done this in the first place, but not sure if there is a better option for debugging purposes.

Comment: @cnu - you're right adjusting the livenessProbe and readinessProbes is required in some scenarios